# Setting a value in a column in dataframes with more than 2 level index

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change a value in a column with dataframe that has two level index with non unique values:

```
df = DataFrame(data = {'col1':[1,2,3,4],'col2':[1,2,3,4]}, index =MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','b'),('a','c'),('a','b'),('a','d')]))
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df
        col1   col2
a   b    1      1
    b    3      3
    c    2      2
    d    4      4
```

I want to change a value in 'col2' where the index is not unique, like in the case of `(a,b)`:

```
df.ix['a','b']

        col1  col2
a   b    1     1
    b    3     3
```

Lets say I want to change the '1' in 'col2' to a different number (assume I dont know that the '1' is located in the first row, I need to search in which row is he and then change it)

I've tried the following:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index(['level_0','level_1','col1'])
```

which yields a uniquely indexed dataframe:

```
                       col2
level_0 level_1 col1    
  a        b     1      1
                 3      3
           c     2      2
           d     4      4
```

but when I trying to change the value in place using the .ix mechanism, I get the following error:

```
df.ix['a','b',1,'col2'] = 3
IndexingError: only tuples of length <= 2 supported
```

Any Ideas on how to do that? is changing columns values of non-unique two level indexed dataframes or three level or more uniquely indexed dataframes really impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the levels as a tuple

```
In [12]: df.ix[('a','b'),'col2'] = 3

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
     col1  col2
a b     1     3
  b     3     3
  c     2     2
  d     4     4

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

this syntax

```
df.ix['a','b']
```

'works' because it can guess what you are trying to do, but is not robust nor recommended. Always use a tuple with a multi-index.

```
In [19]: df.reset_index()
Out[19]: 
  level_0 level_1  col1  col2
0       a       b     1     1
1       a       c     2     2
2       a       b     3     3
3       a       d     4     4

[4 rows x 4 columns]

In [20]: df.reset_index().set_index(['level_0','level_1','col1'])
Out[20]: 
                      col2
level_0 level_1 col1      
a       b       1        1
        c       2        2
        b       3        3
        d       4        4

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

In order to work on the new multi-index, you need to assign to a variable

```
In [21]: df2 = df.reset_index().set_index(['level_0','level_1','col1'])

In [22]: df2.ix[('a','b',1)] = 10

In [23]: df2
Out[23]: 
                      col2
level_0 level_1 col1      
a       b       1       10
        c       2        2
        b       3        3
        d       4        4

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Jeff, this is not working good - it changes both ('a','b') entries while Im looking to change only the first row.

Comment: also, this does not work: `df.ix[('a','b',1)]`. Not only that, it seems there is a bug since once I run that the index was re-seted.

Comment: virtually all operations return a *new* dataframe (except if you use ``inplace``). So are you sure that you were operating on the correct frame? Your example seems to indicate that you are printing the output of the ``set_index`` operation, but your selection is *before* this. In general ``inplace`` operations are harder to read as well.

Comment: Jeff, if he wants to assign values, shouldn't you use `.loc` instead of `.ix`?

Comment: they are equivalent in this case (and generally they are as well; more validation on ``loc`` is the difference)

Comment: Jeff you were right, I forgot to assign the df after setting the index. I do have two comments on the your answer, consider editing it if you feel I have a point. First, isnt it better to use `df.ix[('a','b',1),'col2'] = 10` rather then `df.ix[('a','b',1)]=10` since the first is making sure the assignment would take place in the original df and not a copy. The second thing - You havent address the problem of non-unique keys. you wrote `df.ix[('a','b'),'col2'] = 3` this is assigning the value 3 to both rows while I was looking for a method to assign to a specific row according to some logic.

Comment: both assignments are the same in that they work on the original df (in this case they are exactly the same because you only have 1 coumn), ``df.ix[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value`` is the idiom. Your second example will work as well, you are just selecting more rows than 1.

Comment: It pays to read thru the docs a bunch: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html; they go into depth of what works and why and how to do lots of things.